# Issue when saving related objects in SonataAdmin form

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata

im new to SonataAdmin/ frameworks, and I'm struggling with rather complex form. I've already tried solutions and tips provided in other questions, with no success.
The problem is, I cannot save one entity (called Sectors) to the database; it is One-To-Many relationship.

Here is the code:

```
Sector.php:
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Offer", inversedBy="sectors")
    * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="offer_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="SET NULL")
    */
private $offer;


Offer.php:
    * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Sector", mappedBy="offer", cascade={"persist"})
    */
private $sectors;

OfferAdmin.php:
    $repositorySector = $this->getModelManager()->getEntityManager('AppBundle:Sector')->getRepository('AppBundle:Sector');
    $sector_s = $repositorySector->findByEvent($event);

    $formMapper
    ->add('sectors', 'entity', array(
            'mapped' => true,
            'class' => 'AppBundle:Sector',
            'choices' => $sector_s,
            'required' => true,
```

While sending/saving the form an error appears that in sectors "the given value is incorrect". 
I'd be grateful for any advice.